# Rule of Replacement and Rule of Inference

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

My question is how I can solve this argument. Can you please help me?

1. $(V\implies \lnot W)\land(X\implies Y)$
2. $(\lnot W\implies Z)\land(Y\implies\lnot A)$
3. $(Z\implies\lnot B)\land(\lnot A\implies C)$
4. $V\land X\therefore \lnot B\land C$

Comment: I've never seen anything like that string of characters. What is it?

Comment: @GitGud: I think I might have figured it out.

Comment: I edited the text based on the title and some guessery. I hope I caught the intended sense.

Comment: Note to erna taguran: The $.$ and $\land$ symbols can both be used for "and", but the latter seems to be more common these days.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld, I was interpreting the question, and I figured `>` meant $\implies$ and `.'.` was supposed to be $\therefore$. I have no idea why any of this is written as it is, with some premises connected by $\land$ and others on separate lines.

Comment: @dfeuer: (I deleted the earlier comment; this might be a better version of it.) I think the last line might better be translated as $$V\land X\vdash\neg B\land C$$ Do you agree?

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld: my understanding is that $\therefore$ and $\vdash$ actually mean the same thing (from this follows that), but I don't have enough background in logic to be sure.

Comment: @dfeuer: Ah, thanks. I have not seen the first used in precisely this way, but that is probably due to my ignorance.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld The ones that I know are quite different from either are $\implies$ (which is an expression within the logic) and $\models$, which I don't yet understand in the least.

Comment: @dfeuer Nice catch.

Answer (score 1):

Each step you will need to prove this uses the same laws of deduction: [hypothetical syllogism](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Hypothetical_Syllogism) and $\land$-elimination, except that at the end you need $\land$-introduction. Or maybe you're using a whole different sort of system. You havem't told us.

Comment: You don't need hypothetical syllogism to derive the conclusion from these premises.  You *can* use it (so I'm not down-voting your answer, just leaving a comment), but you don't have to do so.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I did not intend to say that was the *only* way. Hypothetical syllogism can be derived from other principles, and there are all sorts of different sets of rules you can start with to end up with all of them. I was just giving a suggestion.

Comment: I didn't interpret what you wrote as saying that hypothetical syllogism was the only way.  I did interpret you as saying that if you deduced the above from the assumptions given, then you would necessarily have used hypothetical syllogism.  That if-then statement is not true.  I apologize if you did not intend that if-then statement... the word *need* usually seems to imply something like that to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your "primitive" or "basic" or "non-derived" rules of inference are.  So, I'll derive your conclusion using just four rules and the assumptions you have given (otherwise I'd need axioms... and your system might not have any axioms... heck it might not even qualify as a system at all since it might not have any well-formed formulas, like my first symbolic logic text).

1. Detachment (abbreviated Co): From ($\alpha\implies\beta$) as well as $\alpha$, we may infer $\beta$
2. Conjunction-in (abbreviated Ki): From $\alpha$, as well as $\beta$ we may infer ($\alpha \land \beta$)
3. Conjunction-out left (abbreviated Ko-l): From ($\alpha\land\beta$), we may infer $\alpha$.
4. Conjunction-out right (abbreviated Ko-r): From ($\alpha\land\beta$), we may infer $\beta$.

You can "solve" this by discharging all the conjunctions with the conjunction-out rules, then using the detachment rule several times, and then for the very last step use the conjunction-in rule.  Your text may call those rules *names* like "simplification, modus ponens, and something else" or "conjunction elimination, modus ponens, and conjunction introduction."  If you have a rule which says something like "from $(\alpha \implies \beta)$, as well as $(\beta \implies\gamma)$, we may infer $(\alpha\implies\gamma)$,"  you can solve this in another way, but then you'll probably end up using more rules of inference, so I prefer not to do that here.  But, you might want to write that proof, since it comes as shorter in length (though I suspect many logicians probably would maintain it as taking more for granted than what I do below on very solid grounds).

I strongly suggest that you try writing the proof *now* before reading the following or only read parts of the proof and try to finish it yourself as you read.

Your first assumption goes

1. $(V\implies \lnot W)\land(X\implies Y)$ your second assumption goes
2. $(\lnot W\implies Z)\land(Y\implies \lnot A)$ your third assumption goes
3. $(Z\implies\lnot B)\land(\lnot A\implies C)$ your fourth assumption goes
4. $(V\land X)$   by Ko-l on 4 we get 5
5. $V$    by Ko-r on 4 we get 6
6. $X$    by Ko-l on 1 we get 7
7. $(V\implies \lnot W)$ by Ko-r on 1 we get 8
8. $(X\implies Y)$ by Ko-l on 2 we get 9
9. $(\lnot W\implies Z)$ by Ko-r on 2 we get 10
10. $(Y\implies \lnot A)$ by Ko-l on 3 we get 11
11. $(Z\implies \lnot B)$ by Ko-r on 3 we get 12
12. $(\lnot A\implies C)$ by 7, 5 Co we get 13
13. $\lnot W$ by 8, 6 Co we get 14
14. $Y$   by 13, 9 Co we get 15
15. $Z$   by 14, 10 Co we get 16
16. $\lnot A$  by 15, 11 Co we get 17
17. $\lnot B$  by 16, 12 Co we get 18
18. $C$  by 17, 18 Ki we get 19
19. $(\lnot B \land C)$

Answer (score 0):

$\fbox{Given}$

[1] $(V\implies \lnot W)\land(X\implies Y)$

[2] $(\lnot W\implies Z)\land(Y\implies\lnot A)$

[3] $(Z\implies\lnot B)\land(\lnot A\implies C)$

$\fbox{Assume}$ ($V\land X$). From ($V\land X$) by *conjunction elimination*:

[4] $V$

[5] $X$

From (1–3) by the *transitivity* of the arrow:

[6] $V \Longrightarrow \lnot B$

[7] $X \Longrightarrow \lnot C$

From (4 & 6) and (5 & 7) by *modus ponens*:

[8] $\lnot B$

[9] $C$

Conjoining (8 & 9):

[10] $~\lnot B \land C$

$\fbox{Therefore}$ ($1$–$3$), ($V \land X$) $\vdash$ ($\lnot B \land C$)

Comment: Is "transitivity of the arrow" a rule of inference?  To me it sounds like as a property of the arrow, which has a connection to the rule of inference "from ($\alpha$⟹$\beta$), as well as ($\beta$⟹$\gamma$) you may infer ($\alpha$⟹$\gamma$)."

Comment: My use of modus ponens and &-elim may have given you the impression that I'm also taking that to be a rule of inference. You're absolutely right; it's not. It's a _property_, as you noted, of the arrow that I'm appealing to in order to shorten the proof. If you're seeing a way of proving this in fewer steps and with more standard rules, please feel free to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is a formal proof that needs to be completed.
one possible completion of the proof is
5. v          step 4, simplification
6. v>~w       1 simplification
7. ~w>z       2 simplification
8. z>~B       3 simplification
9. ~w         5,6 modus ponens
10. z         9,7 MP
11. ~b        8,10 MP
12. x>y       1 simplification
13. y>~a      2 simplification
14. ~a>c      3 simplification
15. x         4 simplification
16. y         12,15 MP
17. ~a        13,16 MP
18. c         14,17 MP
therefore ~b^c          11,18 addition/conjunction
most of this proof is just modus ponens and simplification. if you are at least somewhat familiar with these laws of inference, this proof should make sense now